# Local notification repeat, swift

Tags: swift, timer, notifications, alert

I have an app which uses local notifications to send out an alert style notification. The whole point of the app is that it sends out a silent notification at first (no sound involved) and if the user does not interact with it another notification gets sent out 10 seconds later. The problem I'm having with this is that as its an alert (needs to be an alert), if the user does not interact with it, it does not get dismissed. Therefore the second notification (with sound) does not replace the first one. Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I can get the second notification to still pop up (preferably replace the first) if the first notification is not interacted with before the second one gets sent?

Comment: Looks like you're looking for an iOS Messages app style notification. Right?

Comment: Hi, I solved the problem but thanks for the reply. What I ended up doing is using a single notification. The way I worked around the audio problem was by making the first 10 seconds of sound blank then introduce a ringer for the next 20 seconds. This way I got the effect I wanted to achieve with just a single notification

Comment: Hi, I want to get notification when app is terminated and if app is not running then again I want notification every 72 hours. How can I achieve this ? Is it possible with local notification? Also, I am getting issue with local notification - I restart the device. I don't force-quit the app. And now the notifications don't trigger anymore. I need to open the app again. –